# Recursive function in namespaced Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a site that I've namespaced (`NS.something.functionA()`, etc) for sake of organization. I want to have a recursive function within this namespaced Javascript, but when the function tries to call itself, I get an `undefined is not a function` error.

http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/Jwz6g/

```
var timeoutInt = 2000;
var NS = {};
var resultsElement = document.getElementById('results');

NS.recur1 = (function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        NS.recur1();
        resultsElement.innerHTML += 'recur1 re-occuring!<br/>';
    }, timeoutInt);
})();

(function recur2(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        recur2();
        resultsElement.innerHTML += 'recur2 re-occuring!<br/>';
    }, timeoutInt);
})();

NS.recur3 = (function(){
    (function realRecur3(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            realRecur3();
            resultsElement.innerHTML += 'recur3 re-occuring!<br/>';
        }, timeoutInt);
    })()
})();
```

`recur1()` is the function I am having a problem with. `recur2()` is how I've seen recursion work before in JS. `recur3()` was an idea I was playing around with (not ideal, but definitely a solution).

#### Is there any way to make the recursive function `recur1()` work?

Comment: @FilipPeyton the fiddle bellow gave you the solution for your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NS.recur1 = (function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    NS.recur1();
    resultsElement.innerHTML += 'recur1 re-occuring!<br/>';
  }, timeoutInt);
})(); // << This () invokes the function you just wrapped
```

So `NS.recur1` is not a "function", but the return of that invocation.

So when you call `NS.recur1()`, you are calling `recur1()` against `undefined`, since the invocation doesn't return anything.

Simple alternative would be to not invoke at assignment, but at some later point

```
NS.recur1 = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    NS.recur1();
    resultsElement.innerHTML += 'recur1 re-occuring!<br/>';
  }, timeoutInt);
};

NS.recur1(); // begin recursion
```

Comment: Explains the issues with my code, terminology, and how to fix. +1 and accepted. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

```
(function recur1(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        recur1();
        resultsElement.innerHTML += 'recur1 re-occuring!<br/>';
    }, timeoutInt);
})();
```

will do it.

You can name function expressions, and when you do, the name is bound to the result of the function expression in the function's body.

The [language spec](http://es5.github.io/#x13) explains

> The production
> *FunctionExpression* : `function` *Identifier* ( FormalParameterList<sub>opt</sub> ) { *FunctionBody* }
> is evaluated as follows:
>
> ...
>
> Call the CreateImmutableBinding(N) concrete method of envRec passing the String value of Identifier as the argument.

Comment: Mike, really?! That will not help the guy! And seems very nasty code, it's even worst than what he already has...

Comment: And besides you recur1 name for anonymous function name desvirtualizes the concept of namespacing he his trying to setup, as recur1 being called is no more NS.recur1 but recur1 that is visible only within the closure... very dark code!

Comment: @JaõaPinho, By "dark code", do you mean "obscure code"?  I ask because I haven't heard code referred to as dark before.

Comment: Loool, it's kind of an expression sounds better in Portuguese actually :D!

Comment: I remember seeing somewhere that this technique doesn't work in >IE9. Maybe it was a variable declaration of a self executing named function... Anyone know about this?

Answer (score -2):

First recur1 is not a function, it's a closure, function and closure (function that executes himself wrapping some internal logic) are different things and you are messing them both.

I think that what you want is to declare the functions, and then, call one of them, to trigger a cyclic recursion timed by a flag called timeoutInt, so you are kind of creating code flows that update something with timeoutInt milliseconds.

```
 var timeoutInt = 2000;
 var NS = {};
 var resultsElement = document.getElementById('results');

 NS.recur1 = function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
         NS.recur1();
         resultsElement.innerHTML += 'recur1 re-occuring!<br/>';
     }, timeoutInt);
 };

 NS.recur2 = function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
         NS.recur2();
         resultsElement.innerHTML += 'recur2 re-occuring!<br/>';
     }, timeoutInt);
 };

 NS.recur3 = function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
         NS.recur3();
         resultsElement.innerHTML += 'recur3 re-occuring!<br/>';
     }, timeoutInt);
 };
```

Use the code above and start from this point.

Here is a further push to help you out: http://jsfiddle.net/Jwz6g/1/ (working example)

Comment: Identical to kwon's answer. Thanks for your help! +1

Comment: @FillipPeyton yes indeed, with the little detail that i answered you first, so kwon had opportunity to look at mine first and improved it, but that's ok, i'm glade you found a way to solve your problem.